# Generalizing non-crossing pairings to trees (or more general graphs)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions

A non-crossing pairing of size $n$ is commonly defined by linearly arranging $n$ objects and pairing them up with "brackets" that don't cross. Equivalently, if $a<b<c<d$, then we can't pair as $(a,c), (b,d)$.

I'm curious about the following generalization: the linearly arranged objects can be thought of as forming a linear graph with edges connecting neighboring elements as in $\cdots i-1 \leftrightarrow i \leftrightarrow i+1\cdots $. Now what if the objects are connected in some other graph type, say for example, a tree? Now the condition would be: take the unique path connecting $b-d$. If $c$ is on this path and $a$ is not, then we can't pair as $(a,c), (b,d)$.

Are there any results on counting this type of structure? The holy grail for me would be the generating function $f(z)=\sum_n a_n z^n$ where $a_n$ counts the number of non-crossing pairings on any rooted plane tree with $n$ edges.  Even knowing the generating function up to a few unknown constants would be fine.

I've managed to come up with a counting argument and write down a horrible-looking functional equation involving $f'$ and terms like $f(x)$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{1-\sqrt{x}}\right)$, which I can describe if anyone's interested (it would take a bit to write out and I'd prefer to do it only if it'd help). I'm worried that this might be as good as it gets, but I still had some hope that I had overlooked a simpler counting argument.

Comment: What are some examples / other rules this pairing has to follow? For example, must each element be in at least / at most / exactly one pair? As you've described it, it looks like these should be completely unique on 'linear paths' when they exist.

Comment: @BrandonduPreez Why unique? There are as many of these as balanced parenthetical expressions like $((())()(()))()$ which are known to be counted by the Catalan numbers.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh, I see. From the first paragraph it was not apparent to me that pairs were themselves paired and so on. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @BrandonduPreez I think I may have confused you further... I don't think pairs are themselves paired. But if you have $a,b,c,d$ in a line then you can form the pairs $(a,b)$ and $(c,d)$, corresponding to $()()$, or form the pairs $(a,d)$ and $(b,c)$, corresponding to $(())$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Aah. Thank-you for the patient explanation ^^